# Resulting print from a fax is different from a print from a computer.

Tags: css, dpi, printing-web-page, rightfax, print-style

[image: Weird dots in a fax's printed black and white text]
Any idea what would cause a fax's printed text to look like this. 
I think it could be a dpi issue, the odd thing is all the text that is printed out with white dots in it is directly inside an html tag. I have some text elsewhere on the page not directly wrapped in a span/h1,h2,h3,h4/p tag and it is printing out correctly. Also a gif image on the page is printing out with a similar result. The color is set at #333 on all elements. Font size is in pixels as well. Would setting it to points help? Looking for ideas to fix this with print css.

Comment: What is this fax you speak of?

Answer (score 0):

The difference was the black that was being used. The text in the image is #333 and I switched the color of the text to #000000 for "true black" and that fixed it!